# When an Isomorphism between two algebras is an equivalence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, universal-algebra, direct-product, algebras

I'm currently involved in the study of algebraic structures, and there's a concept that seems to appear every so often.
Given an Algebra $ A=<A,F_i> $ an isomorphism $ f $ is a bijective function that preserve the operations of the algebra.
The example I want to recall to make my case involve direct representation of algebras.
A direct representation of an algebra is an isomorphism between an algebra $ A $ and $ \prod(A,B_i) $ ($ B_i $ is a family of similar algebras to $ A $). It is known that if $ \theta_i=ker(f_i) $, then the image of the epimorphism $ f_i $ goes directly to $ A/\theta_i $ as for the first homomorphism theorem the conditions are satisfied  and exists an immersion (that is an isomorphism, since they're all epimorphisms) from $ A/\theta_i $ and $ B_i $ of the direct representation.
So at the end of the story, $ A $ is completely determined by its congruences, and $ A/\theta_i=B_i $ (not only isomorphic).
The question rely exactly here: why this isomorphism is actually an equivalence?
[sumup of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA9eE.jpg)

Comment: I really don't understand why you brought all that stuff to ask that simple question, but an isomorphism is an equivalence just because the relation in the class of algebras of the same similarity type given by the isomorphism is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. Note here that I used the term class of algebras and not set, since they form a proper class, but if you allow an equivalence relation to be defined in a proper class (exactly the same way) then the answer is almost trivial.

Comment: Being a bijective function and respecting the algebra operations essentially means that you are renaming the elements of $A$, without changing any material properties.